# How to erase all elements in a boost:multi_index applying a "deleter"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a boost::multi_index_container with **raw pointers** ( yes, not the best idea, but sadly I cannot change it ... ) and I need to delete all the elements freeing the memory ...

Is there any way to configure a delete functor in boost::multi_index_container and call some kind of clear method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The idea is to use a RAII container, like a smart pointer.

This way you can be sure a deleter runs whenever items are erased.

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdceb4e67fa77750)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct Demo {
    Demo(int id) : id(id) {}
    int get_id() const { return id; }

    ~Demo() { std::cout << "some kind of deleter runs :)\n"; }
    private:
    int id;
};

typedef multi_index_container<boost::shared_ptr<Demo>,
        indexed_by<
            hashed_unique<const_mem_fun<Demo, int, &Demo::get_id>>>
        > HostContainer;

int main()
{
    {
        HostContainer testHosts;
        testHosts.insert(boost::make_shared<Demo>(42));
    }

    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```

Prints

```
some kind of deleter runs :)
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... the problem is that have to use raw pointers ... It is an old code I cannot change ...

Comment: Then the answer is no. (How can it be old code, and still the problem is new?)

Comment: Because raw pointers are used on many points in the code ... These pointers are stored in a set-like container but now I need to search by another key ... so I am trying to substitute the container ...

Comment: So, how is the lifetime of pointers managed now? Because `std::set` doesn't have a `erase_and_delete` member either. Perhaps Boost Intrusive is interesting to you http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/erasing_and_disposing.html

Comment: Well ... it is not a std::set but a set-like container ... The container is traversed and the pointers deleted    ... -_- ...

Comment: so you could do the same, since you don't want to change how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @Sehe's answer, you can have a smart pointer that implicitly accepts raw pointers so that the user code need not change:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fb8a4f0526abd64)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

template<typename T>
struct implicit_shared_ptr:boost::shared_ptr<T>
{
  implicit_shared_ptr(T* p):boost::shared_ptr<T>(p){}
};

struct Demo {
    Demo(int id) : id(id) {}
    int get_id() const { return id; }

    ~Demo() { std::cout << "some kind of deleter runs :)\n"; }
    private:
    int id;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
        implicit_shared_ptr<Demo>,
        indexed_by<
            hashed_unique<const_mem_fun<Demo, int, &Demo::get_id>>>
        > HostContainer;

int main()
{
    {
        HostContainer testHosts;
        testHosts.insert(new Demo{42});
    }

    std::cout << "done\n";
}
```